# Trying to create a simple form that will display an error if nothing is filled in

Tags: javascript, html, forms, innerhtml

I just started learning javascript recently and am taking some classes, for one of my classes, I had to create a simple form.

There is supposed to be javascript that will display error messages, if the form is not filled out when the submit button is pressed.

Nothing happens when the button is pressed, I'm not even sure if the function is being ran at all.

I didn't put in any "document.write"s, I followed the instructions step by step, but still I cannot get it to work properly.

I'd appreciate any help I can get, thank you very much.

```html
<html>



<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


function register(){

 var x = new Array();
 x[0] = document.getElementById('name').value;
 x[1] = document.getElementById('lname').value;
 x[2] = document.getElementById('email').value;
 x[3] = document.getElementById('pw').value;
 x[4] = document.getElementById('pwc').value;
 
 var h = new Array();
 h[0] = <span style="color:'red'>Please type first name!</span>";
 h[1] = <span style="color:'red'>Please type last name!</span>";
 h[2] = <span style="color:'red'>Please type email!</span>";
 h[3] = <span style="color:'red'>Please type a password!</span>";
 h[4] = <span style="color:'red'>Please confirm password!</span>";
 
 var divs = new Array("mname", "mlname", "memail", "mpw", "mpwc");
 
   for(i in x){
   
   
    var error = h[i];
    var div = divs[i];
    
    
    if(x[i])==""){
    
    
     document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = error;
    
    }else{
    
     document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "OK!";
              
    };
   
   
   };
  };

</script>



<form>

 <table border="1">
  <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td><td><div id ="mname"></div></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/></td><td><div id ="mlname"></div></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></td><td><div id ="memail"></div></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" name="pw" id="pw"/></td><td><div id ="mpw"></div></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Confirm Password:</td><td><input type="text" name="pwc" id="pwc"/></td><td><div id ="mpwc"></div></td></tr>
 </table>
 <br />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="register();" />

</form>




</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made few mistakes, one in span string and another in if statement. Rest all looks fine!

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zog1h7f6/

```
function register(){

var x = new Array();
x[0] = document.getElementById('name').value;
x[1] = document.getElementById('lname').value;
x[2] = document.getElementById('email').value;
x[3] = document.getElementById('pw').value;
x[4] = document.getElementById('pwc').value;

var h = new Array();
h[0] = "<span style=color:red>Please type first name!</span>";
h[1] = "<span style=color:red>Please type last name!</span>";
h[2] = "<span style=color:red>Please type email!</span>";
h[3] = "<span style=color:red>Please type a password!</span>";
h[4] = "<span style=color:red>Please confirm password!</span>";

var divs = new Array("mname", "mlname", "memail", "mpw", "mpwc");

        for(i in x){


            var error = h[i];
            var div = divs[i];


            if(x[i]===''){

                document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = error;

            }else{

                document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "OK!";

            };


        };
    };
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot...that syntax seems to get me a lot. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to do this in small steps;

1. Check if `register()` function gets called first.
2. Inside `register` function, try to get one element value first, say for `id="name"` by doing, `document.getElementById('name')` and testing if you get a value when you submit with a value specified for the name field.
3. Try setting some values to the div. I suggest testing this in chrome inspector console or firefox inspector console. For example something like `document.getElementById('mname').innerHtml = '<span>Testing this</span>'`
4. Once you are comfortable in using the individual pieces, you should be able to string it all together.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I do have a question though. Is there like a debug function on any software? Because I feel that would be useful, kinda like Visual Studio does for C++. I've been using notepad++, brackets, and sometimes dreamweaver CS6 and CC. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Intellij webstorm, eclipse,  net beans all work. But you can simply use sublime text or notepad++ and use the browser for debugging. Read a bit about chrome inspector

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Script, i think its a little bit more cleaner

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


function register(){

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value,
        lName = document.getElementById('lname').value,
        email = document.getElementById('email').value,
        pw = document.getElementById('pw').value,
        pwc = document.getElementById('pwc').value;
          if(name !== '' && lName !== ''&& email !== '' && pw !== '' && pwc !== ''){
                 alert("succes");
            }else{
                  alert("sorry fill all inputs");
              }
        };

</script>
```

Comment: defiantly a lot cleaner haha. I was just following the way it was done by my instructor. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error where you are defining your error messages:

```
var h = new Array();
h[0] = <span style="color:'red'>Please type first name!</span>";
h[1] = <span style="color:'red'>Please type last name!</span>";
h[2] = <span style="color:'red'>Please type email!</span>";
h[3] = <span style="color:'red'>Please type a password!</span>";
h[4] = <span style="color:'red'>Please confirm password!</span>";
```

You should either alternate between quotes (ie wrap the whole string in ' and use " on the inside or vice versa), or escape the double quotes in your string like this.

```
var h = new Array();
h[0] = "<span style=\"color:red\">Please type first name!</span>";
h[1] = "<span style=\"color:red\">Please type last name!</span>";
h[2] = "<span style=\"color:red\">Please type email!</span>";
h[3] = "<span style=\"color:red\">Please type a password!</span>";
h[4] = "<span style=\"color:red\">Please confirm password!</span>";
```

Comment: I think that `'` of `color: 'red'` is unnecessary.

Comment: Voteddown...First not a proper solution. You also forgot to include error in if statement!